# How to find ids of flash textboxes and buttons and set Text in said textboxes and click said buttons in flash webpages

Tags: javascript, c#, html, flash

im working on web page automatization, a way to save peoples time from uncessessary clicks, right now ive successfully automated a very boring data filling web site with a big number of pages and loads of textboxes, this website is html, i use VS2013 C# with WebBrowser control

this is easelly achievable:

Changing TextBox text:

```
HtmlElement ele1 = null;
ele1.InnerText = textBox2.Text;//username
ele1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordtxtbox");
ele1.InnerText = "mypasswordText";
```

Clicking Button:

```
ele2.InnerText = textBox2.Text;//username
ele2 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton");
ele2.InvokeMember("click");
```

To know the element ids or other property, a simple inspect element will do as it shows the entire page structure with each element property clearly detailed.

This works as intended for html pages, however im now facing a page with flash content, the entire page content is mostly flash actually, starting with the typical username and password textboxes and the login button.

Now, exactly what i was doing before with the htmlelement i want to achieve with this flash page, but i can only find the ID of the flash window with inspect element and ive searched the web on how to find the ids/names of the flash elements (by flash elements i mean flash window objects like buttons and textboxes) without any luck.

So how can i find their properties?
How can i change textboxes text and click buttons?

Best Regards,
Eugen.

Comment: You can't access flash objects, flash script must implement js interaction for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if that is so then how can i type text in textboxes and click butons?

Comment: I mean by that programmatically

Comment: Search for SendKeys, that will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the SendKey tip but there has to be a better way, look at this:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/index.html

As you can see i can control that flash textbox and send it a text easelly making the webbrowser control to navigate to a link with those javascript parameters, but, i can do that because i know the textbox id because the author of the page tells us so, how can we get the id of the textbox in any other website that doesnt tell us directly its id?

Comment: "flash js commands", as I said, the flash must implement a JavaScript interface to allow other programs to control it's content.